# Echo issue in video chat app

Tags: ios, xcode, echo, videochat

I am working on a video chat app where I am getting an issue that my sound repeats like an echo...

According to me, the output sound became the input of that phone and that's why this echo issue is caused.

It's working fine when we use headphones, all the sounds and mic input work  perfectly, but in speaker it starts creating noise and echo issue.

I am using a simple broadcast method to stream the video.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Do you have both test devices nearby? Try taking one to another room.

Comment: i have tried through the different room also. But the main issue is our device mic capture the speakers voice as an input which creates this issue.

Comment: 1. video chat on Desktop or Mobile?, Since you tagged ios and you use headset.
2. Flash video chat or Webrtc ?
Interest to help can come from only clear questions!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using webrtc? The echo/screeching is pretty common when you have have two devices publishing and subscribing to each other in a close vicinity. There's really no way to "resolve" it currently - generally I just mute at least one of the devices when testing.

Comment: But i have to create a functionality in which we have to convert the live streams into video call. And its creating so much noise and echo.